# swift FileManager.default.createDirectory() on linux not working

Tags: swift, linux, swift3, vapor

Using swift vapor, on mac it is working fine, on linux my async call with Jobs dies at

`try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: directoryPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)`

I'm printing the directory path before this line of code (the path is correct so far) and the print statement after this line is not getting executed, instead the log file shows:

> Jobs caught an error: The operation could not be completed

The `directoryPath` is:

```
/.../FOO/.../Public/images/items/2017/05/15/
```

Until the directory `2017` all dirs exists, but not the last two `05` and `15`. On mac if they not exists, they got created. On linux it throws the error mentionend above.

Comment: Are you sure you have *write permission* on the `2017` directory?

Comment: all files have the same owner and group. As the compiled apps ownership is FOO:www-data, so the `2017` directory. So I think it should have write access